# How to create a batch file that generates multiple batch files with commands in them?

Tags: batch-file

This is what I am trying to accomplish,
A main batch file and inside that batch file it will generate a new batch file, But that new batch file will generate another batch file and that batch file will have 2 commands in it.

I know, its long. srry

I can do ALL of it BUT I run into this one problem.

```
echo echo start co2 ^& start co1 ^> A2.bat > A1.bat
```

(This goes into the main batch file)

My problem is that the & needs to stay inside and not activate until the third batch file, Because it activates on startup of `A1` it summons *A2* but theres nothing inside *A2* because it already executed both commands which I don't want it to be doing.

I know you might ask, Why the heck do you want a batch file to generate a batch file that will generate ANOTHER batch file with commands in it? The answer is because I am trying to make one master batch file for my computer. Cleans up the desktop ect.

**REVIEW**

I need a master batch file that will generate a batch file which will than generate another batch file that will have 2 commands in it. I have it ALL coded but the & executes the commands before A2 which I don't want.

```
echo echo start co2 ^& start co1 ^> A2.bat > A1.bat
```

If you want put this into a *txt* file and make it a batch file and run it it will generate *A1* you click *A1* and it will generate *A2* I want the 2 commands to be in *A2* so if you click *A2* it will execute the 2 commands.

YES I am new to batch scripting I tried to research how to do this but I still cant find out how.

Comment: Despite this being a poor way of achieving your goal, have you tried multiple carets, perhaps **`^^^`**.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment:

```bat
@Echo @Echo @Start co2^^^&Start co1^>"A2.bat">"A1.bat"
```

This should, when run, produce this in `A1.bat`:

```bat
@Echo @Start co2^&Start co1>"A2.bat"
```

Which should, when run, in turn produce this in `A2.bat`:

```bat
@Start co2&Start co1
```